# Subscript out of bounds error while computing accuracy at different cutoffs

Tags: r

I have constructed a logistic regression and now I want to calculate the predictive accuracy for various cutoff values ranging from 0 to 1. This is the for loop I have been using. But I am getting

> subscript out of bounds

Here predtrain contains 300 predicted output probabilities each ranging from 0 to 1. Each value is compared to cutoff `eff`. Finally a table/confusion matrix has to be generated comparing the original values (train$CAN) with f1. Some thing like this:

```
tab
# pred2
#     0   1
# 0   1  93
# 1   0 206
```

code I have written is this:

```
predtrain <- predict(logreg1, newdata = train, type = 'response')
eff<-seq(0,1,by = 0.05)
for (i in 1:length(eff) {          
  f1 <- ifelse(predtrain > eff[i], 1, 0)
  t1 <- table(train$CAN, f1)
  effy <- (t1[1,1]+t1[2,2])/(t1[1,1]+t1[1,2]+t1[2,2]+t1[2,1])
  eff[[i]] <-effy 
}
```

Comment: Please avoid to post screenshot when it is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting subscript out of bounds errors is that you're trying to create confusion matrices with cutoffs like 0 and 1 -- this will create a confusion matrix with a single column (all predictions are either positive or negative), causing code like `t1[2,2]` to cause your error.

In reality all you're trying to do is to compute the predictive accuracy at different cutoffs, which can be accomplished without creating tables at all with something like:

```
cutoffs <- seq(0, 1, by=0.05)
eff <- sapply(cutoffs, function(cutoff) {
  sum((predtrain > cutoff) == train$CAN) / length(predtrain)
})
```

To see this in action, let's consider a small example model:

```
set.seed(144)
x <- runif(100)
train <- data.frame(x, CAN=as.numeric(runif(100)+x >= 1))
logreg1 <- glm(CAN~x, data=train, family="binomial")
predtrain <- predict(logreg1, newdata = train, type = 'response')
```

Now we can get the predictive accuracy at each cutoff:

```
eff <- sapply(cutoffs, function(cutoff) {
  sum((predtrain > cutoff) == train$CAN) / length(predtrain)
})
plot(cutoffs, eff)
```

[image]

You could alternately use a package like the ROCR package to grab metrics. For instance, here is how you could grab the sensitivity at each cutoff:

```
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(predtrain, train$CAN)
perf <- performance(pred, "sens")
eff <- sapply(cutoffs, function(cutoff) max(perf@y.values[[1]][perf@x.values[[1]] >= cutoff]))
plot(cutoffs, eff)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.... I was trying to generate new data frame f1 and then compare it knowing that looping is not efficient.

Comment: But to calculate something like specificity and sensitivity doesn't it become more difficult? I have written using two for loops, I know it is not very effective but I do get the table from which I can calculate performance variables. Can this code be improved?

Comment: @SairamReddy I've updated the code to demonstrate how to use ROCR, which can grab any number of different outcomes across a range of cutoffs. By switching `"sens"` to other measures (which you can read as `?performance`), you'll be able to grab other outcome metrics.

Answer (score 0):

But to calculate something like specificity and sensitivity doesn't it become more difficult? I have written using two for loops, I know it is not very effective but I do get the table from which I can calculate performance variables. Can this method be improved?

```
enter code here
    z <- seq(0,1,by = 0.05)
    t1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(z))
for(i in 1:length(z)) {
            predtrain <- predict(logreg1, newdata = train, type = 'response')

                for(j in 1:length(predtrain)){
                     predtrain[j] <- ifelse(predtrain[j]>z[i], 1, 0)
                }
        t1[[i]] <- table(train$CAN, predtrain)
      } t1
```